# Why Is Python PriorityQueue Not Popping the Lowest Value Priority?

Tags: python, search, queue, nodes, priority-queue

I have two classes `PriorityQueue` and `PriorityQueueWithFunction` that cannot be altered in any way, defined as:

```
class PriorityQueue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.heap = []
        self.count = 0

    def push(self, item, priority):
        entry = (priority, self.count, item)
        heapq.heappush(self.heap, entry)
        self.count += 1

    def pop(self):
        (_, _, item) = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        return item

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self.heap) == 0


class PriorityQueueWithFunction(PriorityQueue):

    def __init__(self, priorityFunction):
        self.priorityFunction = priorityFunction
        PriorityQueue.__init__(self) # super-class initializer
```

I have implemented an A* Search algorithm which uses the `PriorityQueueWithFunction` class. It takes two arguments. The first is a `problem`, which is an abstract representation of a search problem that has the starting state of where the SearchAgent and Goal are. The second parameter is an **already admissible** `heuristic`. This is the implementation I have:

```
def aStarSearch(problem, heuristic):
    closed = set() # A set to implement GraphSearch for efficiency

    # Two variables so that the passed function can recognize argument types before
    # they've been called
    node = problem.getStartState()
    cost = 0

    # Instantiate the real fringe. The function is cost + heuristic value
    fringe = PriorityQueueWithFunction(lambda x: cost + heuristic(node, problem))
    fringe.push((problem.getStartState(), 0, [])) # The first state with no cost or action

    while not fringe.isEmpty():
        node, cost, directions = fringe.pop()

        if problem.isGoalState(node):
            return directions

        if not (node in closed):
            closed.add(node)

            # getSuccessors(state) method expands all child nodes of node
            for node, direction, costOfStep in problem.getSuccessors(node):
                fringe.push((node, cost + costOfStep, directions + [direction]))

    if fringe.isEmpty():
        print "No solution was found."
        return []
```

I have checked this implementation many times and it does indeed find the goal solution path every time if it's possible, however it will not find the goal solution **optimally**.

I have debugged this and it came down to the fact that the `PriorityQueueWithFunction` is not acting like a `PriorityQueue`. It takes out the "first in" as opposed to the entry with the lowest priority integer.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here? What about my implementation would make my `PriorityQueueWithFunction` act as if it were a `Queue` and not a `PriorityQueue`?

Comment: There are several weird things with your code. The only definition of push we can see takes two arguments (in addition to self), whereas the one you're using takes a tuple of three elements. Are you missing the code redefining push in the PriorityQueueWithFunction class by any chance?

Comment: No, I am passing a tuple of three elements as the item because we need to keep track of the state, the cost, and the directions. The second parameter is automatically parsed when the `lambda` function is called on the new instance. This will always happen due to the nature of the curried function passed to `PriorityQueueWithFunction` when instantiated. When I run this with the other classes within the program it works as a parameter.

Comment: I understand that, but you posssibly forgot to show us the redefinition of push in your PriorityQueueWithFunction code, because its priorityFunction attribute (as it appears in PriorityQueueWithFunction's `__init__`) is never used anywhere else in the code fragment you've shown us.

Comment: It calls the super 'PriorityQueue' so it inherits push/pop from that

Comment: I understand how inheritance works. However, the only version of push you've shown us does not make use of `self.priorityFunction` to compute the priority, and takes two positional arguments with no default value, whereas you call it with only one argument every time you use it. If I run your code using dummy values for `problem` and `heuristic`, I get a `TypeError: push() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`. So if there is additional code in these classes, please show it.

Comment: By the way, considering your implementation of PriorityQueue, if every element were to end up with the same priority, it would behave exactly like a FIFO queue, so seeing the part where the priority gets computed is especially relevant.

Comment: You know, that may be where the issue lies. So how would I incorporate that new argument if I'm not allowed to change the classes? There is no additional code for either of those, and the code that I implement doesn't need anything further shown

Comment: In this case, just use the standard `PriorityQueue`, and compute yourself the priority whenever you push an element in the queue (by doing something akin to `fringe.push((node, cost + costOfStep, directions + [direction]), cost + heuristic(node, problem))`

Comment: That worked!... Don't know why my assignment wanted me to use the other one